# Joining tables with Union then adding artificial Column

Tags: mariadb, query, union

I Have joined 2 tables together using `union` as follows

```
SELECT DateTime AS Date, Pupil, DateTime AS Time
FROM tableA
Where Status = 'Pending'
Union
SELECT DateTime AS Date, Pupil, DateTime AS Time
FROM tableB 
Where Status = 'Pending'
Order by DateTime
```

I was wondering if it was possible to add another column to show which table the information has been pulled from

Ie

| Date | Pupil | Time | Table |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xx | xxxxx | xxxx | TableA |
| xx | xxxxx | xxxx | TableB |

Comment: ```.. DateTime AS Date, .. , DateTime AS Time ..``` ???

Comment: @Akina The DateTime field as you can probably tell, provides the date and time together. I have called it twice so that I can set one column to show only the date and the other to show only the time. However, that has nothing to do with the question I am asking

Comment: *I can set one column to show only the date and the other to show only the time.* This may cause problems it you'd process this data. Do correctly: `.. DATE(DateTime) AS Date, .. , TIME(DateTime) AS Time ..`. *that has nothing to do with the question I am asking* @AndrewSayer give an answer. I do not see the reason for to repeat it. PS. IF his answer solves then accept it, please.

Comment: I tried using `.. DATE(DateTime) AS Date, .. , TIME(DateTime) AS Time ..` but for some reason MariaDB doesnt seem to like this and returns an error

Comment: You do something wrongly. This is legal in MariaDB: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZBP6p4LT). Maybe you have not quoted the reserved words used as column names? Reporting about an error you'd provide complete error message..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just include a hardcoded string in your selects.

```
SELECT DateTime AS Date, Pupil, DateTime AS Time
,'TableA' source_table
FROM tableA
Where Status = 'Pending'
Union all
SELECT DateTime AS Date, Pupil, DateTime AS Time
,'TableB' source_table
FROM tableB 
Where Status = 'Pending'
Order by DateTime
```

Note that I’ve changed it to use a `union all` as there’s no need to apply a `distinct` when the rows are now guaranteed to be different.